# Lifting Lie algebra cohomology class to Hochschild cochain

Tags: homological-algebra, lie-algebra-cohomology, hochschild-cohomology

Let $g$ be a Lie algebra, $h\subset g$ an ideal. The associative algebra $N=U(h)\subset U(g)$ can be viewed as a $g$-module.

The Lie algebra cohomology ${\rm H}^*(g,U(g))$ is isomorphic to the Hochschild cohomology ${\rm HH}^*(U(g), U(g))$ where the second $U(g)$ is viewed as a $U(g)$-bimodule by the standard left and right multiplication. By Cartan-Eilenberg isomorphism, I can then lift a Chevalley-Eilenberg cochain $\varphi\in{\rm Hom}(\Lambda^p g, U(g))$ to a Hochschild cochain $m\in{\rm Hom}(\otimes^p U(g),U(g))$, such that $\varphi$ is simply the restriction of $m$ to $\otimes^p g$ and then anti-symmetrized.

Now I want to do the same thing with the module $U(g)$ replaced by $N=U(h)$. The problem is that $N$ is not a $U(g)$-bimodule with the standard left and right multiplication, and so analogous Hochschild cochain is not defined. Nonetheless, I think there is a generalization of the above lift, of a class in ${\rm H}^n(g,N)$ to a cochain in $\bigoplus_{p+q=n} {\rm Hom}(\Lambda^p g, {\rm Hom}(\otimes^q N,N))$, that obeys an obvious compatibility condition induced by the inclusions $h\subset g$ and $h\subset N$.

As an example, take $n=2$. What I want to do is to take a cocycle $\varphi\in {\rm Hom}(\Lambda^2 g, N)$ and lift it to a triple $(\varphi,\rho,m)$, where $\rho\in {\rm Hom}(g\otimes N,N)$ and $m\in {\rm Hom}(N\otimes N,N)$ ($m$ is a Hochschild 2-cocycle), such that the appropriate cocycle condition is satisfied, and the compatibility condition under restriction to $h$ is obeyed, namely $\varphi(a,b) = \rho(a,b)$ when $a\in g$, $b\in h$, and $\rho(a,x) = m(a,x)-m(x,a)$, when $a\in h$ and $x\in N$.

Obviously such a triple gives a cohomology class of ${\rm H}^2(g,N)$. I want to show that the reverse is true, namely given a class in ${\rm H}^2(g,N)$ there is a lift to such a triple. I tried to prove this using Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence but did not succeed. Please help!

Comment: Just to rephrase my question, what I want is an analog of the map from a Chevalley-Eilenberg cochain to a Hochschild cochain, in the case when $N=U(h)$ is not a $U(g)$-bimodule. There is a trivial construction where one takes $U(h)$ to be a $U(g)$-bimodule by adjoint action on the left and trivial action on the right. This is not what I want, because one does not get the standard Hochschild cochain in this way. Really what I want in the end is a deformation class of the associative algebra $U(g)$ but with "restricted coefficients" in $N\subset U(g)$.